# reopen get "commit changes" window in IDEA after code analysis check

Tags: intellij-idea

When I do git->"Commit Directory", I get a "Commit Changes" window. I select some changes and write a commit message. Then I click the "commit" button. IDEA performs code analysis and suggests to see errors/warnings. After I see them, I need to select the necessary changes from scratch (commit message already ok).

How to reopen this window with all changes marked if I close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a known issue and there is a ticket created for it:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106867

Please vote for it.

As a workaround in order to keep the selected changes, you may use **no-modal commit view**. 
It can be enabled in **Settings | Version Control | Commit Dialog | Check "Commit from Local Changes without showing the Commit Dialog"**